# Using regex with notepad++ to get specific words only

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to get export the following format into normal wording format

```
#EXTINF:0 tvg-id="ChannelName" tvg-name="ChannelName" group-title="CATEGORY" tvg-logo="jpglink",AXN http://streamlink.m3u8
```

im able to do one at time using notepad++ with bookmarks but it can only work if i search for m3u8 or jpg but i can't get the tv-id or tv-name neither group-title name so the export of above format should look like this

ChannelName ChannelName CATEGORY jpglink http://streamlink.m3u8

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: What are the requirements? How do you know what should be removed? And try `[^\s=]+="(.*?)"(,\S+)?|#EXTINF:\d*\h*` to replace with `$1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your input and expected output, it seems you need to remove:

- `#EXTINF:0`-like pattern (`#EXTINF:` followed with digits)
- Any attribute name with an equal sign and double quotes around the values you need to keep,
- Any "additions" after the attribute values that are added after a comma

I suggest the following pattern:

```
[^\s=]+="(.*?)"(,\S+)?|#EXTINF:\d*\h*
```

And replace  with `$1` (to restore the values you need).

[image]

Comment: the code works fine and thanks for your help just stuck on one situation  on regular txt file the stream link is on second line.  This is the way it shows up:                                                                                       #EXTINF:0 tvg-id="ChannelName" tvg-name="ChannelName" group-title="CATEGORY" tvg-logo="jpglink",AXN                                                                         streamlink.m3u8

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/d191d3864d2b46f4b7bb34c51b182ad2.png as you can see in code and sample there is ANX which i don;t want to show up. thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, my above pattern works for this string, too. Do you mean you want to obtain a 1-line result? `streamlink.m3u8` should be right after `jpglink`?

Comment: here is screenshot sorry for the trouble http://image.prntscr.com/image/9bfc7490f98c47f0b9b7e8c381d78d0d.png

Comment: Try `[^\s=]+="(.*?)"(,(?:(?!http:).)*)?|#EXTINF:\d*\h*` (maybe even enable *`.` matches newline* option).

Comment: that works thank you so much